# Django. Регистрация нового пользователя

Tags: django

Я пытаюсь сделать регистрацию нового пользователя, но так как я новичок не могу разобраться.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Registr(User):
     """регистрация нового пользователя"""
    user_name = models.CharField('имя пользователя', max_length = 20)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    user_password = models.CharField('пароль', max_length = 50)
```

Пишет такую ошибку:
    email_name, domain_part = email.strip().rsplit('@', 1)
AttributeError: 'EmailField' object has no attribute 'strip'

если добавить strip = True
то пишет:
    super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strip'

Comment: P.S. Регистрацию реализовывай в классе FormView, так как CreateView не хэширует пароль, а в FormView ты сам его захэшируешь

Answer (score 0):

```
user_email = models.EmailField()
```

Оставте так, будет работать.